# How do I exclude a Route from being wrapped by the MaterialApp "builder" function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am wrapping a BlocListener around all pages within my app. This way, I can "listen" to authentication changes (login, logout etc) at the top of the widget tree and then navigate the user to the relevant page once the authentication state changes.

I want to add a landing page (LandingPageView) that shows an animation (ca. 5 seconds) before any other page is supposed to be displayed. My problem is that, if I do it like in the example above, the "builder" of MaterialApp will run immediately (not waiting for LandingPageView animation to finish). It will then navigate the user to either the HomePageView or the LoginView before the LandingPageView has finished and throw an error because the animation Ticker of the LandingPageView is still running at that point.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      fontFamily: "WorkSans",
      colorScheme: lightColorScheme,
      textTheme: mainLightTextTheme,
    ),
    onGenerateRoute: (_) => SplashPage.route(),
    home: const LandingPageView(),
    navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
      // Tried to exclude the LandingPageView, so BlocListener doesn't immediately trigger navigation
      if(child is LandingPageView){
        return child;
      }
      return BlocListener<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        listener: (BuildContext context, AuthenticationState state) {
          switch (state.status) {
            case AuthenticationStatus.authenticated:
              _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(HomePageView.route(), (route) => false);
              break;
            case AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated:
              _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(LoginView.route(), (route) => false);
              break;
          }
        },
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

- I tried to exclude the LandingPageView from being wrapped by the BlocListener, so the user doesn't get piped through immediately. I noticed that the "builder" always returns a FocusScope as child and never a LandingPageView, so I cannot differentiate between what Route the MaterialApp is processing and thus, cannot exclude the LandingPageView.
- I have tried putting the LandingPageView as a child of a MaterialApp above this level. I'd have two MaterialApp widgets in my app though which I don't think is ideal.
- I cannot put the LandingPageView above the MaterialApp as I will lose the Material context to build the UI for the LandingPage.
- I can also not put this navigation logic in the "routes" property of the MaterialApp as I won't have the information to distinguish between the LandingPageView and the other Routes

I know I could potentially wrap all the Routes except for the LanidngPageView with the BLOC Listener but I somehow hope I can avoid this, as it just leads to a lot of duplicate code.

So my question is if it is somehow possible to exclude certain routes from being wrapped within the MaterialApp "builder".

Any help or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Regards